# Errors with svg text elements

Tags: d3.js

I can't figure out why this isn't giving my some basic text elements.  The `cy` attribute is for some reason NAN.  And the positioning is wrong - there's something appearing in the top left corner.  Grateful for pointers.

[A jsfiddle..](http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/177afwn5/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Multiple text groups</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

var width = 400,
    height = 400;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",400)
    .attr("height",400)
    .append('g');

dat = [{"name": "xxxx", "desc": "xxx xxx xxx"}, 
       {"name": "yyyy", "desc": "yyy yyy yyy"},
       {"name": "zzzz", "desc": "zzz zzz zzz"}];

svg.selectAll("text").data(dat).enter().append("text")
    .attr('cx', 50)
    .attr('cy', function(i){ return i * 100; })
    .text(function(d){ return d.name; });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.attr('y', function(i){ return i * 100; })
```

i here is your data element.  I think you meant:

```
.attr('y', function(d,i){ return i * 100; }) //<-- i is now the index
```

**EDITS**

As @LarsKotthoff points out, should be `x` and `y`, not `cx` and `cy`, those be for [circles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle).  I also had to add a  `+ 10` "margin" to shift the first text element onto the page.

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ST9IZ41XbvDAQe762Buq?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Mark.  That's corrected the data, but they're still not positioning right.  Any idea why?

Comment: `text` elements don't have `cx` and `cy`. Use `x` and `y` instead.